# Pixelated font on the external monitor

Tags: display, fonts, display-resolution, external-monitor

Today I bought a monitor and faced the problem of a strange image display on it

Fonts in all programs look very sharp and pixelated (it hurts my eyes to look at them)
I've tried setting antialiasing in the gnome-tweak-tool, but it doesn't do anything

When I set the scaling to 1.25, the picture looks perfect, but everything is huge on the monitor and not convenient

I want to find out how to make a picture of the same quality but without scaling

My system is Ubuntu 22.04
Monitor 21.5 Full HD Samsung F22T350

Comment: Is there another way besides HDMI you can use? Sometimes I have this problem using HDMI. As a workaroud, another solution might be to lower the resolution and then set the scaling to below 1.0 to make everything smaller. It would be nice to know why this happens though.

Comment: Also, have you tried [this method using the Samsung monitor settings](https://superuser.com/a/340961/317065)? This problem usually goes away if I use DVI or VGA instead of HDMI and I guess the setting sort of takes care of that problem while allowing you to keep the HDMI cable.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried the option on the link - it was configured correctly
lowering the screen resolution and then scaling it down only makes things worse
yes, there is an option to connect DVI cable, but I need to buy one more

Comment: tried to connect Windows through the same cable - everything looks perfect
I tried Live USB Xubuntu (xfce) - it looks better, but not as good as on Windows